# Initialisation during load time vs runtime vs compile-time

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization, runtime, load-time

In the below example, I get an error on compilation

```
int main() {

    int x = 10; // guess this is runtime initialisation
    static int y = x; //guess this is loadtime initialisation

    printf("x = %d, y = %d", x, y);

}
```

Error:

```
    error: initializer element is not constant
```

My understanding is this is related to the way static and global members are initialised as against auto variables. 
I wanted to know the difference between the load time , runtime and  compile-time initialisation I also wanted to know about the element's value getting stored in data section and stack and its effect on initialisation.

Comment: I think load-time and compile-time are the same. At least from the point of view that both occur before run time.

Comment: You should really look your questions up before asking because they may have been already asked and answered. Type in the relevant keywords (`[c]`, `static`, `initialize` here), use google too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say in C there is no difference between compile-time and load-time. The same is not true of C++: POD constants are initialized at compile time, while global/static objects with constructors are initialized at load time.

In your example, you try to initialize a compile-time value with a run-time variable's contents, so it fails. In C++, if `x` were declared `const`, it would be recognized as a compile-time constant and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables came to life before the automatic variable or say local variable so u can't use any variables for initialization of static variable u can only use constants for initialization of static variable.

Load time initialization and compile time initialization  is same in C and runtime initialization is may be not supported in C ..it is supported in C++ but i don't know about C

Comment: Runtime initialization is definitely supported in C. That `x` in `main()` does not even exist outside of run time, so it's created and initialized at run time.

Answer (score 0):

constants are initialized at compile time, while global/static variables are initialized at load time so you cannot initialise global/static variable with load time with run time stack variables
if we can convert x to const(c++) it would run ok.

Comment: some answers below say "there is no difference between compile-time and load-time" ??

Comment: yes in C, order of loading instructions in the code will be determined at compile time